# Loading numeric data from lines matching regex - numpy fromregex

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I am trying to load floating point numbers from a text file with the following format:

```
# random line of text
# random line of text
# keywordtomatch wordtext, wordtext, wordtext with spaces, 751791.000000, text with alphanumeric characters
# keywordtomatch wordtext, wordtext, wordtext with spaces, 751791.000000, text with alphanumeric characters
# random line of text
# random line of text
```

I have so far unable to get following/similar regexes work for me:

```
array = numpy.fromregex(file, r"# keywordtomatch \w+, \w+, \w+, (\d+\.*\d+), \w+", dtype)
```

to read the floating point numbers from lines containing `keywordtomatch` only. Tried to tweak my regex on regex101 with no success.

This seems simple, but not for non-numpy-expers like me :), so a seasoned python can probably help me with a one liner?

Please assume keywordtomatch does not appear elsewhere in the file.

Comment: Why not split each individual lines on a comma, count the number of fields, and convert the n-th field (if available) to float?

Comment: I did that. I would like to construct a regex to do it more elegantly! Being able to construct such a regex would help improve my numpy skills :)

Comment: I don't think learning to handle regexes helps numpy skills; they are different skills. Learning to index arrays with arrays, or being "fluent" with `einsum` may be more of a numpy skill. `fromregex` seems like a convenience function, tagged on to numpy, but not essential to it.

Comment: For what it's worth: `\w` in a regex usually does not include (white)space characters.

Comment: I've seen that function in passing, but never used it, or seen a SO question using it.  I'd have to start by playing with the examples.

Comment: thanks Evert, I meant the combination of numpy.fromregex would be useful to me later on.

Comment: The first step is to make sure your pattern matches one of the desired lines, with the proper number of 'groups'.

Answer (score 0):

Starting small:

```
In [58]: txt = "# keywordtomatch wordtext, wordtext, wordtext with spaces, 751791.000000, text with alphanumeric characters"
In [59]: re.match('# keywordtomatch (\w+)', txt[3])
In [60]: re.match('# keywordtomatch (\w+)', txt)
Out[60]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 25), match='# keywordtomatch wordtext'>
In [64]: _.groups()
Out[64]: ('wordtext',)
```

Lets simplify the text:

```
In [69]: txt = "start word, another, 123, word"
In [70]: re.match('start (\w+), (\w+), (\d+), (\w+)', txt)
Out[70]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 30), match='start word, another, 123, word'>
In [71]: _.groups()
Out[71]: ('word', 'another', '123', 'word')
```

Now copy that `txt` line to a file

```
In [80]: dt = np.dtype('U10,U10,int,U10')
In [81]: np.fromregex('stack42659805.txt', pat, dtype=dt)
Out[81]: 
array([('word', 'another', 123, 'word')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<U10'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<U10')])
```

and it works for multiple lines that match, and skipping ones that don't.

So the rest of the problem is just figuring out a correct pattern.

Generalizing a bit:

```
In [89]: re.match('start (\w+), ([\w ]+), ([\d\.]+), (\w+)', 'start one, two words, 3.4, four')
Out[89]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 31), match='start one, two words, 3.4, four'>
In [90]: _.groups()
Out[90]: ('one', 'two words', '3.4', 'four')

In [91]: pat = 'start (\w+), ([\w ]+), ([\d\.]+), (\w+)'
In [95]: dt = np.dtype('U10,U20,float,U10')
In [96]: np.fromregex('stack42659805.txt', pat, dtype=dt)
Out[96]: 
array([('word', 'another',  123.  , 'word'),
       ('word', 'another word',  123.  , 'word'),
       ('word', 'another and more',  123.43, 'word')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<U20'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<U10')])
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for the helpful comments.

Comment: I was able to solve it by using
```
    pat = r'# Measure ([\w/+_\- ]+), ([\w/+_\- ]+), ([\w/+_\- ]+), ([\d\.]+), ([\w/+_\-^]+)'
    dt = np.dtype('U100,U100,U100,f8,U10')
```